# UK keyboard virtual key code for the @ Symbol

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to map virtual key codes to my UK keyboard layout, but I can’t seem to find the correct code for the @ symbol.

This is coded in Visual Basic:

```
key = Chr(i)
If i = 190 Then key = "."
If i = 222 Then key = "#"
If i = ??? Then key = "'"   ' (this is the one I need)
```

Comment: For future use you could make an application with a single form that handles the form's `KeyDown` event. In the event you could print the keycode of the pressed key in for example a label. `Label1.Text = CInt(e.KeyCode)`.

Comment: not 64 thanks Steve, thanks VV....will keep digging ;o)

Comment: Yep. 64 on my uk keyboard. Check in your Windows settings that your Region and language and keyboard are all set to UK

Comment: Also, what keyboard are you using and also are you using any key mapping software like zboard?

Comment: Also you title is asking about the @ symbol, but the body of your question is asking about the tick' symbol .. which is it? the standard code for @ is 64. For the tick, the code is 39 or the reverse tick is 96.

Comment: My main goal is to get the @ symbol, to do this I need the following 2 lines of code:      

`If i = ??? Then key = "'" 
If key = "'" AndAlso My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then key = "@"     `

The first line should produce a single quote mark and the second line  should then produce the @ symbol if the shiftkey and single quote keys are pressed.

I am using a std UK Keyboard layout with no mapping software.

Answer (score 2):

After a little testing, it seems that you're getting your keycodes from the KeyDown event and not the keypress event. That wasn't clear in your question.

For the tilde/apostrophe, the keycode is 192.

Here's a list of the key codes for future reference:

0    No key pressed

1    The LEFT MOUSE Button

2    The RIGHT MOUSE Button

3    CANCEL KEY

4    The MIDDLE MOUSE Button (three-button mouse)

5    The first x mouse button (five-button mouse)

6    The second x mouse button (five-button mouse)

7    Undefined

8    BACKSPACE

9    TAB

10    The LINEFEED key

11    Undefined

12    CLEAR key

13    RETURN/ENTER KEY (next to letters) also ENTER KEY (on number-pad)

14    Undefined

15    Undefined

16    SHIFT

17    CTRL

18    ALT

19    PAUSE / BREAK

20    CAPS LOCK

21    The IME Hanguel mode key / The IME Kana mode key

22    Undefined

23    The IME Junja mode key

24    The IME final mode key

25    The IME Hanja mode key / The IME Kanji mode key

26    Undefined

27    ESC

28    The IME convert key

29    The IME nonconvert key

30    The IME accept key

31    The IME mode change key

32    SPACE BAR

33    PAGE UP / PGUP KEY

34    PAGE DOWN / PGDN KEY

35    END

36    HOME

37    LEFT ARROW KEY

38    UP ARROW KEY

39    RIGHT ARROW KEY

40    DOWN ARROW KEY

41    The SELECT key

42    The PRINT key

43    The EXECUTE key

44    The PRINT SCREEN key

45    INSERT

46    DELETE

47    The HELP key

48    0/) KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

49    1/! KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

50    2/@ KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

51    3/£ KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

52    4/$ KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

53    5/% KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

54    6/^ KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

55    7/& KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

56    8/* KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

57    9/( KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

58    Undefined

59    Undefined

60    Undefined

61    Undefined

62    Undefined

63    Undefined

64    Undefined

65    A and a KEY

66    B and b KEY

67    C and c KEY

68    D and d KEY

69    E and e KEY

70    F and f KEY

71    G and g KEY

72    H and h KEY

73    I and i KEY

74    J and j KEY

75    K and k KEY

76    L and l KEY

77    M and m KEY

78    N and n KEY

79    O and o KEY

80    P and p KEY

81    Q and q KEY

82    R and r KEY

83    S and s KEY

84    T and t KEY

85    U and u KEY

86    V and v KEY

87    W and w KEY

88    X and x KEY

89    Y and y KEY

90    Z and z KEY

91    The left Windows logo key

92    The right Windows logo key

93    CONTEXT-MENU KEY (KEY WHICH SIMULATES A RIGHT-MOUSE CLICK)

94    Reserved

95    SLEEP/STANDBY KEY ON KEYBOARD

96    0 KEY (on number-pad)

97    1 KEY (on number-pad)

98    2 KEY (on number-pad)

99    3 KEY (on number-pad)

100    4 KEY (on number-pad)

101    5 KEY (on number-pad)

102    6 KEY (on number-pad)

103    7 KEY (on number-pad)

104    8 KEY (on number-pad)

105    9 KEY (on number-pad)

106    * KEY (on number-pad)

107    + KEY (on number-pad)

108    The separator key (ENTER key on number-pad)

109    - KEY (on number-pad)

110    . KEY (on number-pad)

111    / KEY (on number-pad)

112    F1

113    F2

114    F3

115    F4

116    F5

117    F6

118    F7

119    F8

120    F9

121    F10

122    F11

123    F12

124    F13

125    F14

126    F15

127    F16

128    F17

129    F18

130    F19

131    F20

132    F21

133    F22

134    F23

135    F24

136    Unassigned

137    Unassigned

138    Unassigned

139    Unassigned

140    Unassigned

141    Unassigned

142    Unassigned

143    Unassigned

144    NUM LOCK

145    SCROLL LOCK

146    OEM specific

147    OEM specific

148    OEM specific

149    OEM specific

150    OEM specific

151    Unassigned

152    Unassigned

153    Unassigned

154    Unassigned

155    Unassigned

156    Unassigned

157    Unassigned

158    Unassigned

159    Unassigned

160    The left SHIFT key

161    The right SHIFT key

162    The left CTRL key

163    The right CTRL key

164    The left ALT key

165    The right ALT key

166    BROWSER BACK KEY ON KEYBOARD / INTERNET-CONTROL (Windows 2000 or
later)

167    BROWSER FORWARD KEY ON KEYBOARD / INTERNET-CONTROL (Windows 2000 or
later)

168    BROWSER REFRESH KEY ON KEYBOARD / INTERNET-CONTROL (Windows 2000 or
later)

169    BROWSER STOP KEY ON KEYBOARD / INTERNET-CONTROL (Windows 2000 or
later)

170    BROWSER SEARCH KEY ON KEYBOARD / INTERNET-CONTROL (Windows 2000 or
later)

171    BROWSER FAVORITES KEY ON KEYBOARD / INTERNET-CONTROL (Windows 2000
or later)

172    BROWSER HOME KEY ON KEYBOARD / INTERNET-CONTROL (Windows 2000 or
later)

173    MUTE KEY ON KEYBOARD / MEDIA-CONTROL (Windows 2000 or later)

174    VOLUME DOWN KEY ON KEYBOARD / MEDIA-CONTROL (Windows 2000 or later)

175    VOLUME UP KEY ON KEYBOARD / MEDIA-CONTROL (Windows 2000 or later)

176    The media next track key (Windows 2000 or later)

177    The media previous track key (Windows 2000 or later)

178    The media Stop key (Windows 2000 or later)

179    The media play pause key (Windows 2000 or later)

180    The launch mail key / E-MAIL KEY ON KEYBOARD / INTERNET-CONTROL
(Windows 2000 or later)

181    The select media key / MEDIA KEY ON KEYBOARD / MEDIA-CONTROL
(Windows 2000 or later)

182    The start application one key (Windows 2000 or later)

183    The start application two key (Windows 2000 or later)

184    Reserved

185    Reserved

186    ; and : KEY

187    =/+ KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

188    , and < KEY

189    -/_ KEY ON KEYBOARD (above letters)

190    . and > KEY

191    / and ? KEY

192    @ and ` KEY ON KEYBOARD

193    Reserved

194    Reserved

195    Reserved

196    Reserved

197    Reserved

198    Reserved

199    Reserved

200    Reserved

201    Reserved

202    Reserved

203    Reserved

204    Reserved

205    Reserved

206    Reserved

207    Reserved

208    Reserved

209    Reserved

210    Reserved

211    Reserved

212    Reserved

213    Reserved

214    Reserved

215    Reserved

216    Unassigned

217    Unassigned

218    Unassigned

219    [ and { KEY

220    \ and | KEY

221    ] and } KEY

222    # and ~ KEY

223    Used for miscellaneous characters; it can vary by keyboard

224    Reserved

225    OEM specific

226    The OEM angle bracket or backslash key on the RT 102 key keyboard
(Windows 2000 or later)

227    OEM specific

228    OEM specific

229    The PROCESS KEY key (IME PROCESS KEY)

230    Oem specific

231    Used to pass Unicode characters as if they were keystrokes (Windows
2000 or later)

232    Unassigned

233    OEM specific

234    OEM specific

235    OEM specific

236    OEM specific

237    OEM specific

238    OEM specific

239    OEM specific

240    OEM specific

241    OEM specific

242    OEM specific

243    OEM specific

244    OEM specific

245    OEM specific

246    The ATTN key

247    The CRSEL key

248    The EXSEL key

249    The ERASE EOF key

250    The PLAY key

251    The ZOOM key

252    Reserved for future use

253    The PA1 key

254    The CLEAR key

255    OTHER / MISC KEY ON KEYBOARD

Comment: Thanks Gentlemen, works a treat and I really appreciate your help with this .